# Android Fragment created twice orientation change

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

My fragment is being created twice, even though the activity is only adding the fragment once to the content. This happens when I rotate the screen. Also, everytime the fragment's onCreateView is called, it has lost all of it's variable state.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) { // Checking for recreation
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new AppPanelFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

}
```

onCreate in the activity checks for the null savedInstanceState and only if null will add the fragment so I can't see why the fragment should be created twice? Putting a breakpoint in that if condition tells me that it only ever get's called once so the activity shouldn't be adding the fragment multiple times. However the onCreateView of the fragment still gets called each time orientation changes.

```
        public class AppPanelFragment extends Fragment {

            private TextView appNameText;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// This method called several times
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_app_panel, container, false);

// 2nd call on this method, appNameText is null, why?
appNameText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
appNameText.text = "My new App";

    return view;

    }
```

I managed to have the variable state persisted using setRetainInstance(true), but is this the real solution? I would expect the fragment to not be created on just an orientation change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Fragment` lifecycle is very similar to an `Activity`. By default, yes, they will be re-created during a configuration change just like an `Activity` does. That's expected behavior. Even with `setRetainInstance(true)` (which I would say to use with extreme caution if it contains a UI) your `View` will be destroyed and re-created, but in that case your `Fragment` instance will not be destroyed -- just the `View`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So maybe my actual issue is that I am not modeling my fragment correctly. I have some data inside this fragment which I would like to presist when orientation changes. It sounds like I won't be able to do that. Should I be keeping the data abstracted away from the fragment class then? And in which way would that happen here - I do have  PresentationModel with models could be attached on

Comment: If your data is something that can be put into a bundle, use `onSaveInstanceState()` to put data into that bundle, and in `onCreate()` pull it back out if the `savedInstanceState` bundle is non-null.

Comment: That make sense, yes the data could easily be saved on the bundle. That would remove the need for setRetainInstance?

Answer (score 5):

In android, when the phone's orientation is changed, the activity is destroyed and recreated. Now, i believe to fix your problem you can use the fragment manager to check to see if the fragment already exists in the back stack and if it doesn't then create it.

```
public void onCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            AppPanelFragment fragment  = (AppPanelFragment)mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fagment_id);
            if(fragment == null) {
                //do your fragment creation
            } 
        }
    }
```

P.S. I haven't tested this but it should work once you provide the right fragment's id in the findFragmentById method.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit late to answer, but using The Code Pimp answer you can do the next thing:

If the fragment exists in the backstack we pop and remove it to add it back (an exception is thrown if it is added back without removing it, saying it already exists).

The fragment variable is a class member variable.

This method will be called in the onCreate method of the Activity:

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(getFragmentActivityLayoutContainerId()) == null) {
            fragment = getNewFragmentInstance();
        } else {
            fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(getFragmentActivityLayoutContainerId());
            fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        fragmentTransaction.add(getFragmentActivityLayoutContainerId(), fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

The next code will be called in the fragment itself.

It is a small example for a code you could implement in your fragment to understand how it works. The dummyTV is a simple text view in the center of the fragment that receives text according to orientation (and for that we need a counter).

```
private TextView dummyTV;
private static int counter = 0;

@Override
protected int getFragmentLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.fragment_alerts_view;
}

@Override
protected void saveReferences(View view) {
    dummyTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_alerts_view_dummy_tv);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        dummyTV.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("dummy_string"));
    } else {
        dummyTV.setText("flip me!");
    }

    dummyTV.append(" | " + String.valueOf(counter));
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("dummy_string", counter++ % 2 == 0 ? "landscape" : "portrait");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, on orientation change, the activity is destroyed and recreated. Also, Fragments(any) are recreated by the system.

To ensure your application restores to previous state, onSaveInstanceState() is called before the activity is destroyed.

So, you can store some information in the onSaveInstanceState() method of an activity and then restore your application to same state on orientation change.

NOTE: You need not create fragments on orientation change, as fragments are recreated.

Example from http://www.mynewsfeed.x10.mx/articles/index.php?id=15:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if ( savedInstanceState == null ){
          //Initialize fragments
          Fragment example_fragment = new ExampleFragment();
          FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
          transaction.add(R.id.container, example_fragment, "Example");
    } else{
       //control comes to this block only on orientation change.

       int postion = savedInstanceState.getInt("position"); //You can retrieve any piece of data you've saved through onSaveInstanceState()

      //finding fragments on orientation change 
      Fragment example_fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag("Example");

     //update the fragment so that the application retains its state
     example_fragment.setPosition(position); //This method is just an example

    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("position", position); //add any information you'd like to save and restore on orientation change.
    }

}
```